# Difference between upcasting and instantiation of child objects

Tags: c#

I was asked by my teacher to create a project on shape inheritance hierarchy and in the Main() he asked us to create an array of shapes that would store one instance of each of the classes point, circle, and cylinder.

so the code of Main() is here.....

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Shape[] areaOfShapes = new Shape[3];

        areaOfShapes[0] = new Point(10, 5);
        areaOfShapes[1] = new Circle(20);
        areaOfShapes[2] = new Cylinder(25,12);

        foreach(Shape item in areaOfShapes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I just want to know if this is upcasting or not. And what is the difference between upcasting and normal instantiation of child objects??

Comment: Could you please provide a full compileable example? You are missing the definitions for Shape etc.

Comment: What does upcasting have to do with instantiation? Perhaps you should explain what "upcasting" and "instantion" means *to you*, and we can move on from there :)

Comment: Simply read [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/polymorphcasting06222007131659PM/polymorphcasting.aspx).

Comment: You need to restrict your examples to two dimensional shapes. As FredrikRedin points out, a point is not a shape...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, The thing which you are using in Main method is called polymorphism in object oriented world.

**Q**. *What polymorphism is?*

**Answer**: **As per MSDN**,

> Polymorphism is often referred to as the third pillar of object-oriented programming, after encapsulation and inheritance.

**Polymorphism is a Greek word that means "many-shaped"** and it has two distinct aspects:

1. At run time, objects of a derived class may be treated as objects of a base class in places such as method parameters and collections or arrays. When this occurs, the object's declared type is no longer identical to its run-time type.
2. Base classes may define and implement virtual methods, and derived classes can override them, which means they provide their own definition and implementation. At run-time, when client code calls the method, the CLR looks up the run-time type of the object, and invokes that override of the virtual method. Thus in your source code you can call a method on a base class, and cause a derived class's version of the method to be executed.

So as per your example, you have one parent class that is Shape. Shape class has three implementation : Point, Circle, and Cylinder.

When you did

```
Shape[] areaOfShapes = new Shape[3];
```

You have created 3 reference(**areaOfShapes**) in stack which will point to Shape objects or objects of child class of Shape object in heap memory.

[image]

Picture is taken from [here](http://www.tlu.ee/~matsak/java/thinking_in_java/TIJ309.htm).

So basically the parent reference can point to child objects in heap but vice versa is not possible.

In case of normal Instantiation you will have reference of any class(let say shape) in stack and object of same class in heap. I mean you will have reference **areaOfShapes** in stack and this reference will point to Shape object in heap.

Read more about Polymorphism here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx

Comment: No, This is from MSDN. Added the link to that page. Thanks @Sinatr

Comment: Thanks so much Mukund and Sinatr

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is upcasting. It's fairly simple :

a) Upcast is when you take an instance of **derived** class instance and then try to cast it to the **base** class. For example you create field that can stroe base class object and instantiate it with derived class. This is when upcast take place (implicit upcast).

```
// implicit upcasting (done by compiler)
Shape instance = new Cirle(10, 5);

// explicit upcasting (when we specify cast operation explicitly)
Shape instance = (Shape)(new Cirle(10, 5));
```

Our instance cannot use members of Circle class anymore because it was cast to Shape class.

b) *"normal instantiation of objects"* is :

```
Shape instance = new Shape(10, 5);
```

Here we just create a new object of type `Shape`. It has access to all members of Shape class but it has no access for Circle's class members. If we create object of type Shape we cannot downcast it to Circle class.

This throws an exception : `Circle instance = (Circle)(new Shape());`

But if we change it to :

```
Shape instance = new Circle();
Circle instance2 = (Circle)(instance);
bool isCircle = instance is Circle; // true
```

It works with no problem at all. Please note that value of isCircle field is set to `true`, this is because even though we upcasted our `instance` back to Shape, but its underlying type is still type of Circle. The upcast operation has just encapsulated members  of derived class and that's all